# MySQL query for shortest & longest length of a field

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

## Problem

I need to return the shortest & longest *city* names along with their respective lengths from a database. I also welcome refinements to this query to make it more elegant.

### SQL Fiddle

I have a sample database & query thus far:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b4a7c/1/0

#### Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT City, LENGTH(City) as len
FROM STATION
WHERE LENGTH(City)=(SELECT MIN(LENGTH(City)) FROM STATION) 
OR LENGTH(City)=(SELECT MAX(LENGTH(City)) FROM STATION)
ORDER BY len
```

#### Current Result

```
Dole    4
Reus    4
Sant'Egidio del Monte Albino    28
```

#### Desired Result

```
Dole    4
Sant'Egidio del Monte Albino    28
```

Comment: What happened to reus?

Comment: The first one alphabetically that is the shortest wins.

Comment: I suppose hackerrank brought you here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using `union all`, `order by`, and `limit` . . . if you just want one example of the longest and shortest names:

```
(select city, length(city)
 from station
 order by length(city) asc
 limit 1
) union all
(select city, length(city)
 from station
 order by length(city) desc
 limit 1
);
```

If you wanted ties, when more than one city matches, then I would do:

```
select s.city, length(s.city)
from station s cross join
     (select max(length(city)) as maxl, min(length(city)) as minl
      from station
     ) ss
where length(s.city) in (ss.minl, ss.maxl);
```

Comment: Gordon: The 1st query works but the 2nd outputs Dole 4 | Sant'Egidio del Monte Albino 28 | Reus 4

Comment: Strawberry or Gordon: Is *join* more or less efficient than *union all*?

Comment: @techsmi Is a spanner more efficient than a hammer? They're different tools for different things. That said, you could test for yourself which query is fastest as quickly as ask here. My money's on GL's first solution - but I might not be right.

Comment: @techmsi . . . There are two cities with the shortest names . . . "Dole' and "Reus".  The second is correct.

Comment: @Strawberry I did test them & GL's 1st & your solution took 1ms according to sqlfiddle so this is why I asked.

Comment: @Strawberry & Gordon: Thanks for your help and input.

Comment: @techmsi . . . You really cannot test the performance of queries on such small tables  A millisecond here or there can be caused by many factors.

Comment: what if there are duplicate results and you only one a single min and a single max?

Answer (score 7):

```
select min(a.city),length(a.city)
from station a
join (SELECT min(length(city)) minlength,max(length(city)) maxlength from station) b
on length(a.city) in (minlength,maxlength)
group by length(a.city)
```

Comment: I'm not really surprised ;-)

Comment: Haha. Yes, I added this comment in because when others come to this answer they will know which solutions work & which don't.